# How to handle when a Firestore document may or may not include a field with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have an existing Firestore database for a project. In a given collection (say "users"), I have the user profile information in each document.

In some documents, I have the field "signupMethod" in the collection while the same field does not exist in some other documents in the same collection.

I need to try to read the signupMethod for each user session in my application. If the document does have the field, the value of the field needs to be used. If the field for the corresponding users document does not exist, I would like to set it to the default value of "Email".

I try the following approach:

```
try {
  if (snapshot.data().containsKey("signupMethod")) {
    wpUserProfile.signupMethod = snapshot.data["signupMethod"];
  } else {
    wpUserProfile.signupMethod = "Email";
  }
} on Exception catch (_) {
  wpUserProfile.signupMethod = "Email";
}
```

But it gives the following error:

```
Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class '_JsonDocumentSnapshot' has no instance method 'call'.
Receiver: Instance of '_JsonDocumentSnapshot'
Tried calling: call())
```

And I try the following instead:

```
try {
   wpUserProfile.signupMethod = snapshot.data["signupMethod"];
} on Exception catch (_) {
  wpUserProfile.signupMethod = "Email";
}
```

And I get the following error this time:

```
Exception has occurred.
StateError (Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform)
```

I do not understand why it does not run the code in the Exception block and set it to "Email".

Does anyone know how I should handle this situation when reading a field from Firestore which may or may not exist in a given document with flutter?

---

ADDENDUM:
(Answer to Peter's question below)

If I print out `snapshot.data`, I get the following output:

```
flutter: Instance of '_JsonDocumentSnapshot'
```

If I print out `snapshot.data()`, I get the following error:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_JsonDocumentSnapshot' has no instance method 'call'.
Receiver: Instance of '_JsonDocumentSnapshot'
Tried calling: call()
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:63:5)
#1      _UserDataProviderState._setUserProfileData
package:wp/widgets/user_data_provider.dart:76
#2      _UserDataProviderState.build.<anonymous closure>
package:wp/widgets/user_data_provider.dart:135
#3      _FutureBuilderState.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/async.dart:782
#4      StatefulElement.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4782
#5      ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4665
#6      StatefulElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4840
#7      Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4355
#8      BuildOwner.buildScope
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2620
#9      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:882
#10     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
package:flutter/…/rendering/binding.dart:319
#11     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1143
#12     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1080
#13     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame
package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:996
#14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1428:13)
#15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
#16     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1236:7)
#17     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:166:10)
#18     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:270:5)
#19     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:129:31)
```

If I just print out `snapshot.data["email"]`, I get the following output:

```
testuser@testuser.com
```

Comment: I think you have to add `()` after `data` when accessing data, for example: `snapshot.data()!["signupMethod"]`. And also if a field does not exist you will get `null`, so you can do simply: `wpUserProfile.signupMethod = snapshot.data["signupMethod"] ?? "Email";`

Comment: @PeterKoltai It unfortunately does not help. I tried and it throws the same error:  "NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class '_JsonDocumentSnapshot' has no instance method 'call'."

Comment: What is the result of `data()`?

Comment: @PeterKoltai I provided more info for your question above. What is the right way of handling such fields that may or may not exist?

Comment: Try `snapshot.data!.data()["email"]` and `snapshot.data!.data()["something"]`, what do you get?

Comment: @PeterKoltai The following worked based on your suggestion:  snapshot.data!.data().containsKey("signupMethod"). Do you think you can explain why it worked in this way? (I will accept it as the answer if you can write this down.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case I assume that `snapshot` contains an `AsyncSnapshot` object. According to the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot-class.html) it has a `data` property. This can be `null`, so it is always recommended to check `hasData` / `hasError` properties before processing the results.

So once you made sure it is not null, `snapshot.data!` will contain the result   of your `AsyncSnapshot`, in this case this is a `DocumentSnapshot`.

Looking at [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html), `DocumentSnapshot` has a `data()` method that will hold the document itself. So finally `snapshot.data!.data()` will be your document, and you can get the fields from it like:

- `snapshot.data!.data()["signupMethod"]`, or
- `snapshot.data!.data().get("signupMethod")`
- (if you need the `id` of the document, it will be in `snapshot.data!.id`)

In both cases you will get `null` if the field does not exists, so you don't need `containsKey`.

**Important**: make sure to check if `snapshot.data!.exists` is `true`, because Firestore will give you the document snapshot even if the data you are looking for can't be found. If `exists` is `true`, you are good to go with the above.